# Hugo version not updating to latest

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hugo

I am trying to work with the [Hugo static site generator](https://gohugo.io/).

**Problem:** Hugo is saying it is updated to the latest version but it is not.

`$ hugo version` 
`Hugo Static Site Generator v0.40.1 linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-04-25T17:16:11Z`

But the latest version is now [v0.70.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases)

**System:**
Windows Subsystem for Linux via the terminal in Visual Studio Code v1.45.0

Any help would be much appreciated thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed it via the `apt` package manager, you might be out of luck there, because the official repositories might not be up to date with the latest version of Hugo.

To update the repositories and install the latest available version of `hugo`, try doing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hugo
```

However, I see it's only getting version `0.6x`.

If you want to use it on Windows, you could try installing it via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/). Both seem to have version `0.70.x` in their repositories, but you'd need to install them first, because they're not Windows out-of-the-box software. Not sure if and how it would work if you use it in the WSL, though.

Otherwise, there's always the good'ol [download the binary and save it](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing/#binary-cross-platform).

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a Debian-based system, e.g. Ubuntu, you can download the appropriate `.deb` from https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases and install it with, for example:

```
sudo dpkg --install ./hugo_extended_0.70.0_Linux-64bit.deb
```

I wrote about this in [footnote 10](https://www.ii.com/themeless-gitless-intro-hugo/#_footnotedef_10) in my [Hugo Tutorial](https://www.ii.com/themeless-gitless-intro-hugo/).

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu package manager "apt" does not contain the latest version of Hugo right now. It needs to be updated by the repo owner or similar.

I solved my problem by following a binary install guide [here](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing/#install-hugo-from-tarball)