# Upgrade hugo version

Tags: version, upgrade, hugo

How can I upgrade my hugo from version 0.55.6 to version 0.69 or 0.70?
I tried `yarn add hugo@0.70` and it returns me:

```
yarn add v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "hugo" that matches "0.70"
? Please choose a version of "hugo" from this list: 
❯ 0.0.3 
  0.0.2 
  0.0.1
```

So I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct package name?  Accoding to `yarn info hugo` there the highest version is 0.0.3, as it is showing you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hugo version not updating to latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677467/hugo-version-not-updating-to-latest)

Answer (score 1):

By those version numbers, it seems you want [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), which is a static site generator built in Go.

[`Yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/) is a package manager for the Node.JS ecosystem, similar to `npm`. It manages Node/JS packages, which are usually hosted on https://www.npmjs.com/.

Some packages aren't only JS, but just add JS wrappers over some other binary. This widens the circle of potential overlap, and as there's no naming convention enforced on the NPM packages, you're bound to be mislead by a name. The [hugo npm package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/hugo) seems to be an interface for some lighbulbs.

To install Hugo, you will probably need to install it separately. Check the [Hugo installation info](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing#quick-install). If you have to use `yarn`, you will have to find a different package that ships the `hugo` binary.